# Insert into SQL Server table using VBA doesn't run with Access 2007 and and SQL Server 2008

Tags: vba, sql-server-2008-r2, ms-access-2007

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()

'CHECKING FOR VALID QUANTITY ENTERED BY USER'

If IsNull(Me![INCOMING_QTY]) And IsNull(Me![OUTGOING_QTY]) Then
MsgBox "Must Enter Valid Quantity."
Me!INCOMING_QTY.SetFocus

'VERIFYING THAT WORKORDER IS NEW'

ElseIf DCount("BASE_ID", "DBO_Paint_Room", "BASE_ID = '" & Me!BASE_ID & "' AND PART_ID = '" & Me!PART_ID & "'") = 0 Then

'INSERTING NEW WORKORDER INTO SQL TABLE FROM FORM FIELDS'

CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [DBO_Paint_Room] ([BASE_ID],[PART_ID],[DESCRIPTION],[USER_1],[DESIRED_QTY],[DESIRED_WANT_DATE],[RECEIVED_QTY],[CURRENT_QTY],[LAST_UPDATE_DATE]) " _
& "VALUES ('" & Me![BASE_ID] & "','" & Me![PART_ID] & "','" & Me![DESCRIPTION] & "','" & Me![USER_1] & "'," & Me![DESIRED_QTY] & "," & Nz(Me![DESIRED_WANT_DATE], "Null") & "," & Me![RECEIVED_QTY] & "," & Nz(Me![INCOMING_QTY], "Null") & ",NOW())"
```

This is the top portion of a Sub that inserts data into SQL Server tables. I built this code offsite with Access 2010 and SQL Server Express 2014. It runs fine in that environment, but when I copied the code into a fresh instance of Access 2007 onsite, it doesn't do anything. No errors and no insert, nothing. I modified it to use a saved "SQLstr" and DoCmd.RunSQL, but then it throws a type mismatch error. Can anyone give me some insight as to what I'm doing wrong? The SQL table design source code is exactly the same as in the test version. The ODBC connection uses the standard SQL Server Driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just went with DoCmd.OpenQuery and a saved Access insert query. It works now.